# Robocopy - ERROR 124 (0x0000007C) Creating Destination Directory

Tags: robocopy

Hoping someone familiar with Windows 10 and Robocopy can help.

I am using the following robocopy command in backup script that is being run as Administrator (yes the real Administrator user ID)

```
runas /user:Administrator backup.bat

robocopy N:\FNL E:\FNL /MIR /E /Z /R:1 /W:1 /V /NP /LOG+:backup.log
```

As long as there have been no new files for directories created in the source folder, in this case `N:\FNL` it seems to run fine.  As soon as I create a directory, for example "Fred", I get the following error:

> ERROR 124 (0x0000007C) Creating Destination Directory N:\FNL\Fred
>   The system call level is not correct.

I have changed file permission for "Authenticated Users" to Full Control and as well have taken ownership of all folders and sub-folders/child objects on the target drive but still get the same error.

Anyone have an idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: sorry/correction - the actual error contains the destination drive letter as follows: ERROR 124 (0x0000007C) Creating Destination Directory E:\FNL\Fred The system call level is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

So I just ran into this a few years after the original post.  My issue was my Windows 10 was using the system path variable and found the Robocopy.exe from the way back old Windows Resource kit.  If you run into this error, make sure you are using the correct version of Robocopy.  Windows 10 has a version in C:\windows\system32.